# 68k Assembler on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, assembly, osx-lion, 68000

I need to do some programming stuff in assembler for the 68k for my college class.
I'm looking for a programm to do it on os x lion. I found easy68k which is running in wine, but I have the feeling that it's not working porperly.
Any guess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Vasm](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vasm/) is an assembler that can be built to target the 68k and works under OS X. Check the compilation notes, but basically the command to build it from source to target the 68k, using motorola syntax is:

```
make CPU=m68k SYNTAX=mot
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same situation, and I've found that Easy68k (http://www.easy68k.com/) works very well under wine.

Also, it is possible to set up a  full Debian/68k system using Aranym (see https://wiki.debian.org/Aranym/Quick).

I'll be writing something about this on my blog, hope it helps.

Source: studying m68k for college class too.

### Cheers,

Snoopy

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the issue where Mac's no longer support 32bit code.

So I had to build [Dockers](https://www.docker.com/).

Example of [mine](https://github.com/scirelli/M68k/blob/master/asm68k/Dockerfile).

```
FROM i386/alpine:latest

COPY ./resources/* /opt/asm68k/

RUN apk add --no-cache wine freetype ncurses && \
    mkdir -p /opt/asm68k/bin && \
    ln -s /opt/asm68k/asm68k.sh /opt/asm68k/bin/asm68k && \
    echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/asm68k/bin' >> /etc/profile && \
    ln -s /opt/asm68k/bin/* /usr/local/bin/ && \
    echo alias ll='ls -lah' >> /etc/profile.d/aliases.sh && \
    wine --version && \
    wine /opt/asm68k/asm68k.exe || echo 'done'

WORKDIR "/tmp"

ENTRYPOINT ["wine", "/opt/asm68k/asm68k.exe"]
```

I also built [binutils](https://github.com/scirelli/M68k/tree/master/binutils) this way, but it was a pain.

Answer (score 0):

The GNU assembler (part of [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) can be built to target the m68k. Run configure with --target=m68k-elf (because COFF output is no longer supported for m68k). You also have the option to install gcc and [newlib](http://sourceware.org/newlib/) if you want to write some of the code in C/C++.