# Motorola MC68xxx

Tags: macos, assembly, osx-mountain-lion, motorola

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [68k Assembler on OS X Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218442/68k-assembler-on-os-x-lion)

I'm going to study a Motorola MC68xxx micro-controller and I'm wondering if there's an assembler for Mac OSX.

Eterm 6.5 is suggested for PC users.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218442/68k-assembler-on-os-x-lion it looks very similar

Comment: You could run eterm under wine.

Comment: 680x0 is a microcontroller now? I remember the days when that'd be called a CPU. :)

Comment: @dusk: Ha, I'm sure it's still called that in some areas. ;)

Comment: @Linuxios I ended up running it under Wine on an old Linux Mint laptop. Works great as long as you don't try to resize the window. ^^